# Python 3.5 vs 3.7 process_time

Tags: python, macos, time, process

I see this problem only on my iMac (macOS Mojave, Version 10.14.3). My Windows and Linux (CentOS) computers have no such problem. Could somebody with iMac confirm this?

**process_time** time (CPU Time) is twice bigger than **perf_counter** (Wall Clock) in a single thread program when I run with the latest Python 3.7 release for Mac OS:

> $ python3.7 test.py
>
> Python ('v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492', 'Dec 24 2018 02:44:43') Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)
>
> CPU time: 15.925813999999999 Wall clock: 7.970086342  Distance: 750

I don't see the same problem with the Python 3.5:

> $ python3.5 test.py
>
> Python ('v3.5.1:37a07cee5969', 'Dec  5 2015 21:12:44') GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
>
> CPU time: 8.09766 Wall clock: 8.108357406000323  Distance: 750

Is it a bug in Python 3.7 or I don't understand something about **process_time**?

Here is the code that I run 'test.py':

```
import time
import sys
import platform

def distance(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return 0
    d = sys.maxsize
    for i, c in enumerate(a):
        d = min(d, ord(c) + distance(a[:i]+a[i+1:], b))
    for i, c in enumerate(b):
        d = min(d, ord(c) + distance(a, b[:i]+b[i+1:]))
    return d

print("Python", platform.python_build(), platform.python_compiler())
cpu = time.process_time()
clock = time.perf_counter()
d = distance("12345", "abcde")
clock = time.perf_counter() - clock
cpu = time.process_time() - cpu
print("CPU Time:", cpu, "Wall Clock:", clock, " Distance:", d)
```

code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the bug in the Python 3.7 and 3.8 binary distribution for macOS from https://www.python.org downloads:

```
    $ python3.8 test.py
    Python version : 3.8.0a2
           build   : ('v3.8.0a2:23f4589b4b', 'Feb 25 2019 10:59:08')
           compiler: Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)
    CPU Time: 16.005979999999997 Wall Clock: 8.014987319  Distance: 750
```

I got the source code from gitHub, compiled on my Mac with the latest compiler, and the problem disappeared:

```
    $ ./python.exe test.py
    Python version : 3.8.0a2+
           build   : ('heads/master:a9df651eb4', 'Mar  5 2019 17:21:48')
           compiler: Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
    CPU Time: 7.2123870000000005 Wall Clock: 7.21903976  Distance: 750
```

Modified the 'test.py' program a little bit to correctly report the Python version:

```
import time
import sys
import platform

def distance(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return 0
    d = sys.maxsize
    for i, c in enumerate(a):
        d = min(d, ord(c) + distance(a[:i]+a[i+1:], b))
    for i, c in enumerate(b):
        d = min(d, ord(c) + distance(a, b[:i]+b[i+1:]))
    return d

print("Python version :", platform.python_version())
print("       build   :", platform.python_build())
print("       compiler:", platform.python_compiler())
cpu = time.process_time()
clock = time.perf_counter()
d = distance("12345", "abcde")
clock = time.perf_counter() - clock
cpu = time.process_time() - cpu
print("CPU Time:", cpu, "Wall Clock:", clock, " Distance:", d)
```

Comment: The bug was a regression introduced in 3.7.0 that was seen whenever Python was built on macOS 10.11 or earlier.  Fix now available and to be released in Python 3.7.5 and 3.8.0b4. See [Issue36205](https://bugs.python.org/issue36205) for more details.